# Python Function/Button Reference/Scope Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple card game. It features a main menu with 4 buttons and 2 images.The 4 buttons are `war`, `garbage`, `instruct`, and `quit_exe`. The `war` button should `command=self.game_war` when it is clicked, and the same for garbage. `instruct` should show how to play, and `quit_exe` should simply quit the application. Let's  take `war` for this problem I have.

## The Goal

I need to have, when clicked, `war` execute the `def game_war(self)` function when it is clicked. When this is clicked, it should `grid_forget()` all the widgets so that it can generate widgets for the game of `war`. It should also, when a button called `return` is clicked, it clears the widgets, and then regenerates the main menu.

#### Requirements

It needs to be able to **start** a game based on a **button** being clicked, and the **game functions** should be able to use the **variables** already referenced to **use, overwrite, and save** those variables, so that it can **forget** the widgets and place new ones. When the game **ends**, it should **forget** the current widgets, **use the pre-referenced variables**, then **regenerate** the main menu.

## The Problems

I get a local variable referenced before assignment error. I tried using `nonlocal` and `global`, but it doesn't seem to work. I need this as this is a requirement.

## Summary

I need to be able to execute a function that can grab and use variables. In this case, I need `war` to call `game_war`, which can access the `war`, `instruct`, `quit_exe`, `garbage`, `usrCrd`, and `cpuCrd` variables to clear them out, then to generate new variables for the game, and then when the game ends, regenerate the main menu widgets.

```
import tkinter
import winsound
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import randint, randrange

class CardGame(tkinter.Frame):

  def __init__(self, root):

    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
    
    #define variables for cards
    crdImg = []
    usrStk = None
    cpuStk = None

    #define card images
    i = 1
    while i < 57:
      i = i + 1
      crdImg.append('img/cards/%s.png' % (i - 1))

    usrStk = crdImg[54]
    cpuStk = crdImg[55]
    
    #define card stacks
    usrCrdImg = Image.open(usrStk)
    usrCrdBg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(usrCrdImg)
    usrCrd = tkinter.Label(root, image=usrCrdBg)
    usrCrd.image = usrCrdBg
    
    cpuCrdImg = Image.open(cpuStk)
    cpuCrdBg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cpuCrdImg)
    cpuCrd = tkinter.Label(root, image=cpuCrdBg)
    cpuCrd.image = cpuCrdBg

    #define empty cell generation
    def empCell(px, py, r, c):
      grid(padx=px, pady=py, row=r, column=c)

    #define buttons
    war = tkinter.Button(self, text="Play War!", command=self.game_war)
    garbage = tkinter.Button(self, text="Play Caravan!", command=self.game_garbage)
    instruct = tkinter.Button(self, text="How to Play", command=self.instruct)
    quit_exe = tkinter.Button(self, text="Quit", command=quit)
      
    #define layout
    usrCrd.grid(row=1, column=1)
    cpuCrd.grid(row=1, column=4)
    war.grid(row=2, column=2)
    garbage.grid(row=3, column=2)
    instruct.grid(row=4, column=2)
    quit_exe.grid(row=5, column=2)
    
  #define game functions
  def game_war(self):
    
    war.grid_forget()
    garbage.grid_forget()
    instruct.grid_forget()
    quit_exe.grid_forget()
    usrCrd.grid_forget()
    cpuCrd.grid_forget()
    print("Debug")
    
  def game_garbage(self):

    print("Debug")

  def instruct(self):

    print("Debug")
  
if __name__=='__main__':
  root = Tk()
  root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
  root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
  CardGame(root).grid(row=5, column=3)
  root.wm_title('Card Game')
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need all of that code to reproduce your problem. Your question would be better if you removed all code that wasn't relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving any variables as instance variables -- they are all local. If you want to save a variable so that you can use it in other methods, save it as an instance:

```
self.war = Button(self, text="Play War!", command=self.game_war)
self.garbage = Button(self, text="Play Caravan!", command=self.game_garbage)
self.instruct = Button(self, text="How to Play", command=self.instruct)
self.quit_exe = Button(self, text="Quit", command=quit)
...
self.war.grid_forget()
self.garbage.grid_forget()
self.instruct.grid_forget()
self.quit_exe.grid_forget()
```

... and so on.

On a side note, you should pick a single method of importing tkinter instead of importing it twice. I recommend "import tkinter as tk", and then use "tk." as a prefix to every widget, because global imports can lead to unclear code.